# Compiler gives warning when adding "query.getResultList()"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, javacompiler

When i use query.getResultList(), THE COMPILER gives a warning.

My Code is:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s.ledger,sum(s.DebitAmt),sum(s.CreditAmt) FROM  VouchersDetailsPO as s WHERE s.Ledger='"+ledgerName+"' GROUP BY s.Ledger");
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
```

Warning text is:

> 1.Start the 'Infer Generic Type Arguments' refactoring
>
> 2.Add SupressWarnings 'uncheck'

But I don't want to use SupressWarnings annotation.

Comment: Can you add the text of warning

Comment: You mean "The compiler gives a warning" perhaps ...

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8972250/2074230

Comment: @iMmo: But the question i have asked is different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to help compiler with type inference. The solution is to replace

```java
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("...");
```

with

```java
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = entityManager.createQuery("...", Object[].class);
```

Comment: getting warning after using your code: The method createQuery(String) in the type EntityManager is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class<Object[]>)

Comment: I can hardly believe it. What JPA / Hibernate version are you using ?